# Error while using QUERY with Importrange function

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use `QUERY` and `importrange` data from another spreadsheet (Say A) into my spreadsheet (say B). However, I want to import only rows from A where Column X in A has the same name as in cell L1 of spreadsheet B.

```
=QUERY(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IJw96gEObg0fE3SF_XfEXFnilNbjLaHwUm7gctZ74/edit#gid=1403434756","Data !A2:K3000"),"Select * where Col11 = "&L1&"")
```

error message:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: JohnSmith

Answer (score 1):

try this one if it works:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1IJw96gEObg0fE3SF_XfEXFnilNbjLaHwUm7gctZ74", "Data!A2:K3000"), 
 "select * where Col11 = '"&L1&"'")
```

or:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1IJw96gEObg0fE3SF_XfEXFnilNbjLaHwUm7gctZ74", "Data !A2:K3000"), 
 "select * where Col11 = '"&L1&"'")
```

and if still no luck then try to change `=` to `matches` or `contains`